# Mysql : daemon doesn't start

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, centos

Few hours ago, Mysql shuts down on my production server. I've tried to restart it with 'service mysqld restart' as usual (I'm on a centos), but:

> MySQL Daemon failed to start.

In my log file, I have :

```
151125 10:53:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
151125 10:53:10  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
151125 10:53:10  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151125 10:53:10  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 6283559
01:53:10 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8384512
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338336 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29) [0x8509b9]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x483) [0x6a3ef3]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x3e59e0f790]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
151125 10:53:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I am losing potential clients every second, so I will appreciate your help, thank you

---

EDIT

Problem solved ! My partition was full :

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        15G   15G  0M  100% /
```

I've deleted some useless backups/logs files and restart mysql.
Thank you

Comment: need more info...hardware specs and buffer/cache settings in your my.cnf?

Comment: have you read :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, I 've found the problem.... My storage was full (df -h => 100%). thank you again